# Create User / Batch Create Users in Asgardeo User Management API with Auto Generated Password

Tags: wso2-asgardeo

Just want to ask how we can create a user using Asgardeo User Management API without providing a password?

Basically we want to replicate this flow but instead of manually doing it on the console, we want to do it from the User Management API.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RL9yB.png)

Here are some of the Endpoints that we tested

POST
https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2
/Users

POST
https://api.asgardeo.io/t/asgardeo/scim2
/Bulk

The password field seems to be a required field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the urn:scim:wso2:schema with "askPassword":"true" should allow you to create the users without providing the password.

Sample Payload of the scim https://api.asgardeo.io/t/tenantName/scim2/Users:

```
{
"emails":
[
    {
    "primary":true,
    "value":"<User Email>"
    }
],
"name":
{
    "familyName":"",
    "givenName":""
    },
"urn:scim:wso2:schema":
{
    "askPassword":"true"
},
"userName":
    "DEFAULT/<User Email>"
}
```

The  will receive the invite request similar to the UI function.

Same approach can be taken with the Bulk endpoint too as mentioned this [medium blog](https://medium.com/identity-beyond-borders/import-users-in-bulk-to-asgardeo-via-api-calls-8f4f6c7643c0)

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is also answered by Dehami Koswatte via Email